# After updating Flutter Firebase receive Bad State: field does not exist - QueryDocumentSnapshot

Tags: firebase, flutter

Prior to the update, document['field'] would result in null if it did not exist. Now it throws a Bad State error. The null response is needed because the field does not exist in some historical data and/or optional data in the Firebase collection. Confirmed this in the following report as well:

https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/3826

Is there a way to capture the error and ignore it or set it to null or empty string?

```
 static Pool dataFromDocument(QueryDocumentSnapshot document) {
  return Pool()
    ..authUID = document.get('authUID')
    ..documentID = document.id
    ..propertyManagerID = document['propertyManagerID'] as String
 }

    static Stream<QuerySnapshot> getData(String authUID) {
CollectionReference poolRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(dataDB);
Query query = poolRef.where('authUID', isEqualTo: authUID.trim());
return query.snapshots();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With null safety, `String` is not nullable. However, `String?` is.

Change the line:

```dart
..propertyManagerID = document['propertyManagerID'] as String
```

To:

```dart
..propertyManagerID = document['propertyManagerID'] as String?
```

Your `Pool` will also have to have the property `propertyManagerID` as a `String?` in the class definition.

Comment: Unfortunately, it errors before it gets to theString? - full error message is: I/flutter (28251): Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform. I had set it to this before the update error to pass a string if the field was missing, but removed it when i saw it did not matter: document['propertyManagerID']  ?? '' as String